# How to add over 100 clickable images in different positions using CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I'm a complete beginner with HTML/CSS/Javascript. However I do have experience with Android Native UI, Layouts,Adapters, Views etc.

So I have a venue that uses the same image/icon for seating. Now I need to position then all relative to the venue. This is basically your traditional seating map UI.

So for example, a hardcoded css code would look like:

```
.parent {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;

}
.image1 {
height:auto;
width: auto;
max-width: 1080px;
max-height: 1080px;
}
.image2 {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 70px;
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 60px; 
max-height: 60px;
}
.image3 {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 140px;
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 60px; 
max-height: 60px;
}

....


.image100{
position: absolute;
top: 1000px;
left: 1000px;
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 60px; 
max-height: 60px;
}
```

Here image1 would be the background(the venue), and image2-100 would be then all the different seats in different positions of the venue and with different orientation. Doing this hard-coded seems like a very unintuitive method.

However, I can't load this dynamically, because say if I had 10 different venues, they would all have different layouts and each seat then needs to be positioned differently.

Is there any type of drag and drop drawing application I can use? Basically I just need a UI that can handle say ~100 custom icon seats with 100 unique ID's  without performance issues (This depends on the server, but I don't want to code it in a way that's heavy for the server to handle).

I'm only using these images to make them return an ID on click, that I will post to my server and "book" it.

Comment: "Is there any type of drag and drop drawing application I can use? " — Probably, but shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Quentin I see, I was just wondering if there was a recognized one people recommend, like how Sketch is recommended for mobile app UI design. 

However, do you think I'd hit any type of performance issue if I did this hard coded like the example above? because I'm okay with it, as this layout going to be reused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion:

Have your server provide a list of seats with a unique ID, for example:

```
[
    { id: 1, image: 'url_to_the_image', coordinates: { x: 1, y 1 }},
    { id: 2, image: 'url_to_the_image', coordinates: { x: 10, y 10 }},
    { 
        // more seats 
    }
]
```

Then you can have HTML like this:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: url(../yourVenueMapImageUrl);
}
```

Then, with javascript, run through your JSON and append your seats as `divs` within `.container`. Add the `ID` as a data attribute, and a `.seat` class. You can also set the `style` to place the seat in a specific position relative to your venue map, using the `coordinates` property.  Finally, add an event handler listening for clicks on elements with that `.seat` class, and get the `ID` attribute. For performance, you can also have a single event handler listening for clicks to any element within `.container`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think this sounds like the proper way of doing things! 

Btw, if I want to make them unclickable and load another picture for when they are booked. Should I have a booked  = false parameter in my database? Then in javascript, do a if statement to check the booked parameter is true or false and make it unclickable? Or is there a more conventional way of doing things?

Comment: That'd be perfectly acceptable. Actually, when you're adding seats, add a class name only to free seats, and apply the event handler to those. Additionally add a class to unavailable seats to, for instance, fade them a little bit so it's obvious that they're not free/clickable.